# Regex positive lookaheads in group to filter out specific character, then backreference filtered group?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, backreference

So in my regex I have a group whose content is a number with dashes:

```
00-111-222-333-44
```

How can I use positive lookahead with the dash character to only select digits in this group, the goal being when I backreference the group later I expect this in my output:

```
0011122233344
```

Something like this, but for the whole string, right now the expression just matches the first number before a dash, that is 00:

```
[0-9]+(?=-)
```

Is there a simpler way to just select all digits inside that group, ignoring the dashes, so I can just backreference the group and get clean digits without dashes?

Comment: Why regex? Can't you just replace all hyphens with empty string to get what you want?

Comment: Well the number is part of a long complex line with a lot of fields and characters, I'm using groups in my regex to select specific fields, and then backreference them in the correct order, I thought it could be possible to just select the digits inside that single regex group.

Comment: Ok May I ask in what language you need this?

Comment: POSIX Extended Regular Expressions, PCRE... I'm currently testing my regex using sed and regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use following perl command to replace all hyphens what are appearing between numbers:

```
perl -pe 's#(?<=\d)-(?=\d)##g'
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use positive lookahead with the dash in this group, so that when I backreference the group later it contains only the digits?

This is impossible with regex. A group can only refer to a complete substring of the input string. Instead of trying to match that, you should apply a two-step approach and use a regex-replace to remove all the dashes before matching.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example of a posix regex replace to eliminate the dashes before applying my second regex and backreferencing my 5 groups in the correct order.

Comment: 5 groups? I though you wanted only one?

Comment: This is my current expression: /(^.*text:\+)(.*);(text.*)(@.*;)(.*$)/
The second group contains my number with dashes: (.*), in the end i reorder the output using: \1\2\4\3\4\5

Comment: I think this should do it then (never used posix): `sed -e 's/-(?=\d)//' -e 's/(^.*text:\+)(\d*);(text.*)(@.*;)(.*$)/\1\2\4\3\4\5/'`

Comment: Hmmmm, the first sed command doesn't work, but I understand what you mean, I'll try something in that direction!

Comment: @f10bit: I might have forgotten a global flag, as in anubhava's answer. Try it with `s/-(?=\d)//g`